# Why does this C code produce a double instead of a float?

Tags: c, types

`celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);`

Is it just a development choice that the C developers decided upon or is there a reason to this? I believe a float is smaller than a double, so it might be to prevent overflows caused by not knowing what decimal format to use. Is that the reason, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is to ensure that any result can be encompassed. so the natural choice is double as it is the largest data type.

Comment: The only reason the natural choice is a double is because of what @Shog9 said: there are doubles in the math so it is being evaluated as a double.

Comment: A `long double` may be of greater range and precision than a `double` and thus is a candidate larger data type.

Answer (score 27):

```
celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);
```

In this expression, `5.0`, `9.0`, and `32.0` are `double`s. That's the default type for a floating-point constant - if you wanted them to be `float`s, then you would use the `F` suffix:

```
celsius = (5.0F/9.0F) * (fahr-32.0F);
```

Note that if `fahr` was a `double`, then the result of this last expression would *still* be a `double`: as Vaibhav noted, types are promoted in such a way as to avoid potentially losing precision.

Comment: Arguably, the question is "_why_ are those literals `double`s?" combined with "why does the expression type remain `double` when it would fit in a `float`?"

Comment: @Tomalak: There's really no way for the compiler to *know* that the result of this expression would "fit" into a float; chances are, some precision will be lost even when stuffing it into a double. I suppose in edge cases where an expression consisted entirely of compile-time known values it would be possible for the compiler to pick a low-precision result type... But this would greatly complicate the rules without providing any real value to the programmer (who has to pick an explicit type for storage sooner or later anyway).

Comment: I know what the answer is; I'm just saying.. I think that's what the question was. :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that the expression is cast to double-precision is because the literals specified are double-precision values by default.  If you specify the literals used in the equation as floats, the expression will return a float.  Consider the following code (Mac OS X using gcc 4.01).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  float celsius;
  float fahr = 212;
  printf("sizeof(celsius) ---------------------> %d\n", sizeof(celsius));
  printf("sizeof(fahr) ------------------------> %d\n", sizeof(fahr));
  printf("sizeof(double) ----------------------> %d\n", sizeof(double));
  celsius = (5.0f/9.0f) * (fahr-32.0f);
  printf("sizeof((5.0f/9.0f) * (fahr-32.0f)) --> %d\n", sizeof((5.0f/9.0f) * (fahr-32.0f)));
  printf("sizeof((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0)) -----> %d\n", sizeof((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0)));
  printf("celsius -----------------------------> %f\n", celsius);
}
```

Output is:

```
sizeof(celsius) ---------------------> 4
sizeof(fahr) ------------------------> 4
sizeof(double) ----------------------> 8
sizeof((5.0f/9.0f) * (fahr-32.0f)) --> 4
sizeof((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0)) -----> 8
celsius -----------------------------> 100.000008
```

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day of K&Rv1, it was encouraged to use float/double interchangeably being as all expressions with floating-point types were always evaluated using `double' representation, a problem in cases where efficency is paramount. A floating-point constant without an f, F, l, or L suffixed is of type double. And, if the letter f or F is the suffix, the constant is of type float. And if suffixed by the letter l or L, it is of type long double.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point constants should have the available highest precision. The result can be assigned to a float without undue trouble.